# Automatic ssh script without expect and without key (with user/password)

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to make a script in bash that connects via ssh to another machine.
I only have user access to this machines so

- I **can't use expect** (It is not installed and I can't install it)
- I **can't install ssh keys**

So I have to log in via username and password.
Is there a way to make my script send my password just using bash?

Comment: check if you have `pexpect` and `python` ...you can do much better with `pxpect`  "if its there".

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `sshpass`, however, it's insecure.

```
sshpass -p YOUR_PW ssh ...
```

That will connect without asking for password.

You might need to add the flag `-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no` to ssh for auto-accepting keys.